# SSRS 2008 how to sum results from the two datasets in one the chart

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am trying to create the chart with 5 different datasets.
One chart line should show the sum from the 2 datasets, but not from the main dataset. I am using `lookup` to access two datasets like

```
=(Lookup(Fields!Name.Value, Fields!Name.Value, Fields!Value.Value, "DSOutflow")) 
+ (Lookup(Fields!Name.Value, Fields!Name.Value, Fields!Value.Value, "DSInflow"))
```

I am getting the empty chart line. 
Each value by itself `=(Lookup(Fields!Name.Value, Fields!Name.Value, Fields!Value.Value, "DSOutflow"))`  or `(Lookup(Fields!Name.Value, Fields!Name.Value, Fields!Value.Value, "DSInflow"))` separately provide a nice line by itself. But I need somehow to sum the values... Can someone help?

Comment: From my testing, the expression seems to be working in my test data...  Are both `Value` fields the same data type?  And you're sure both `Value` fields are populated when you're testing this?  Could you possibly provide some samples of the data you're using?

Comment: How are you getting these datasets? Stored Proc? Why don't you handle combining at the SQL Server?

Comment: I am getting for each Dataset XML strings and parsing them as Text in the DS properties "="<Query><XmlData>"+
          Parameters!XMLParameter.Value
          +"</XmlData></Query>""